# Position a menu entry into a specific location with python

Tags: python, add-on

I have a plugin that selects all polygons by the vertex color:
https://gist.github.com/tamask/2590850
However, in order to use it, I need to search for its menu entry 'Select by color', using the space bar search. Is there any way to position the menu entry 'Select by color' wherever I want? Idealy I want it in the Ctrl+G menu, that is in 'Edit Mode': Select > Select Similar > Select by color?